# Define API server authorized IP range within Azure Kubernetes Services

Tags: azure-aks

Define API server authorized IP range - Is this only limited to set the context (.config file) for executing kubectl or also in terms of API calls for services hosted on AKS pods? How different is this from nginx ip whitelisting annotation?

Answer (score 0):

The API server authorization IP range feature blocks access from internet to the API server endpoint minus the provided whitelisted IP addresses. Pods within the cluster access the kubernetes API thru the internal service on `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local`. The whitelisting annotation for the nginx ingress controller (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range) blocks non-whitelisted IP's from accessing your application running in Kubernetes behind the said ingress controller.

Comment: So basically u mean whitelisting IP on Kubernetes API server will not affect the incoming requests coming from non-whitelisted IPs to nginx ingress controller? Example: IP 200.100.10.10 is whitelisted on API server, but requests coming from 201.101.11.11 will have access open on the ingress controller.

Comment: if you could kindly confirm my understanding

Comment: Yes, the ingress controller runs on a separate Public IP attached on an Azure LoadBalancer in your MC_ resource group. The control plane API run on Azure infrastructure, exposed thru a different public IP. The former whitelist you control via annotations to the ingress resource, the latter via the --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges flag at cluster creation time.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications